# Find the Sum of Columns in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to find the sum of each column in a 2D array but I keep getting large numbers that don't make sense with the values in the array.

Here is my code:

```
int table [4][5] = {
{8,9,7,5,9},
{9,9,10,10,5},
{6,10,11,10,9},
{9,11,5,8,10},
};

for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j =0 ;j<5;j++){
        sum += table[j][i];
        
    }
    cout<<sum<<"  "<<endl;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Comment: Your indices are backwards.  Use `table[i][j]`

Comment: Try renaming your loop variables `row` and `col`. Remember for 2D arrays usually the first `[]` is for the row (in 3D arrays usually the first `[]` is for `z`, 2nd for `y`, 3rd for `x`)

Comment: Also note that `int table[4][5];` is very different from `int table[5][4];`. Are you sure about `table[j][i]`? Perhaps it should be `table[i][j]`?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You're adding `table[j][i];` So, if `i = 3` and `j = 4`, you're trying to access `table[4][3];`, which is out-of-bounds.

If you want to add the column, change your code to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j =0 ;j < 4;j++){
        sum += table[j][i];
    }
    std::cout << sum << "  " <<'\n';
}
```